# Angular ag-grid suppressLoadingOverlay not working in different environment

Tags: angular7, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid in my angular application. I want to suppress the loading overlay. I tried the property

```
  suppressLoadingOverlay: true
```

to the GridOptions. It works on my local machine and not working when deployed to different environment.

Can anyone help what could be the problem?

```
tsconfig.json

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you write your tsconfig.json?

Comment: Can you try to change target to es5. let me know if it work